# How to see what address is called on form submit

Tags: javascript, oracle

I have access to a web page that is connected to an Oracle AS report services database.
There are a few fields and drop down boxes to add in filters like date ranges etc
After everything is filled in you hit a button named submit and then a save dialog box comes up, asking you to pick a location where you want the results of your query saved (in excel format)

Id like to pull this button apart so I can insert the code into an access database. This will save users having to go to this webpage all the time and can just stay in the database they are working in.
Looking at the source of the web page there is a bit of javascript but I can't really see how the query parameters are being passed to oracle.
I can see the web address which is like `www.servername.com/reports/rwservlet?` so im guessing there should be parameters after the ?

Is there a way to intercept the submit button message so I can read it?
Or is there another better way?

Comment: Use the developer tools in you browser of choice and inspect the network information

Comment: Thanks for the tips. No wonder I couldn't figure it out. IE8 doesnt have network information in its developer tools. I'll need to upgrade my browser to even try this solution. Haven't got admin rights at work to do it though. This will be interesting.